# Mongoose update values only if changed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way in mongoose to update document only if the values changed?

Something like

```
User.findAndUpdateOnChange({query}, data, function(err, user){

});
```

I am very new to node js. Any help would be great.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to first use get query and then compare, if compare result is false then use update query. Otherwise don't

```
User.find({'key': 'Value'}).exec(function(err, result){
  if(result.key !== 'your new value'){
    user.update({query}, data, function(err, user){

    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Very bad approach !!